# Change Quartz.NET job name without deleting associated triggers

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I’m creating a durable job on startup using Quartz.NET with ASP.NET. The job is created with an explicit group and name, if the job implementation class is refactored (e.g. moves namespace) then all associated triggers are deleted.

```
services.AddQuartz(q => {   
        q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory();

        q.AddJob<MyService.Jobs.TestJob>(opts => opts
            .WithIdentity("MyJob", "MyGroup")
            .StoreDurably());
    //…
    }
```

Is there a way to prevent this and have the new implementation or refactored version of the existing job continue to run for those triggers or at least error on startup?

```
q.AddJob<MyService.NewJobsImplementations.TestJob>(opts => opts
            .WithIdentity("MyJob", "MyGroup")
            .StoreDurably());
```

Answer (score 0):

You might get away with custom ITypeLoadHelper which would hold a mapping from old names to new names and then load with new name. Running an type name update in the db is the easiest of course. Make sure you have backups.

The easiest solution for detecting the problem would have tests checking for name changes using VCS controlled blessed file, fail build if there are unplanned changes.